# Laravel Mix: npm run production doesn't work on production server

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm

I am using Laravel 5.4 with mix to compile my assets. I have a weird problem with "npm run production". When I run "npm run production" on my mac all works fine with valet. But after deploying with forge to my production server it seems that the script isn't even running. Also there are no errors or warnings in my chrome console.

When I run run "npm run dev" all works fine, even on the server.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Do you need to do this on production? I compile mine of my dev box, then deploy them to live.

Comment: I run "npm run production" on my mac and then I deploy.

Comment: "But after deploying with forge to my production server it seems that the script isn't even running" At this point, are you talking about on production or your Mac?

Comment: sorry for being unclear. After running "npm run production" I deploy the compiled assets to my production server. With "script isn't running" I mean that the Javascript does nothing. I also tried to add a simple alert() to the top of my JS but nothing. The compiled scripts works locally with Valet.

Comment: Can you see that they are loaded, in the network tab of Chrome?

Comment: yes, the file is loaded. I've just tried to only compile a simple alert() and this works find, also on the production server. Could it be a problem with babel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140034/discussion-between-mick-and-grundig).

Comment: thanks a lot for this, I just found the issue. The problem was an "unexpected identifier" from a vue.js template, but as the vue warnings are disabled in production it was a bit tricky to find...

Comment: No worries, glad you found it.

Comment: For anyone with this issue, be sure that you are not naming "directory components" with a capital "Index.js". It should be "index.js". This works in dev but fails in production!